# valums Ajax-Upload onComplete responseJSON always is empty !

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I'm using [ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)  in a ASP.Net forms app.

I need to send a string hash which identifies the file once it is saved on the server.

I'm doing it in the ashx handler emitting a json string, but no matter what i send from the server, in the javascript i'm getting an empty object... what am I doing wrong?

This is the snippet for the on load method on the ashx
    // EDITED
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

```
ProcessFile(context.Response);
context.Response.Write("{\"success\": true, \"hash\": " + _myHash + "}");
```

And this is the on complete

```
onComplete: function(id, file, responseJSON) {
    console.log(responseJSON);
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the correct headers from your ashx code-behind?

Comment: i'm using ContentType = text/plain... is that correct? what should be?

Comment: what other headers should I take into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes i had to do to the fileuploader.js file so it could work:

```
    this.log("innerHTML = " + doc.body.innerHTML);      
    // replace <pre> tags from IE Frame
    var content = doc.body.innerHTML.replace(/<pre>/gi, '').replace(/<\/pre>/gi, '');

    try {
        response = eval("(" + content + ")");
    } catch(err){
        response = {response: content};
```

I also changed the way it emits the response in case of JSON errors:

```
        var response = xhr.responseText;

        try {
            response = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        } catch(err){
            // emit an object with the offending responseText
            response = {responseText: response};
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read server/readme.txt included in the package?

> You should return json as a text/html

Answer (score 1):

Use property responseType of AjaxUpload function. Set it to "json".

Like this:

```
new AjaxUpload("#importButton",{
  action: "upload.html",
  name: 'name',  
  responseType: "json",
  allowedExtensions: ['xml'],
  onSubmit : function(file, ext){
  },
  onComplete: function(file, response){
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the headers I set when returning JSON data:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

When they are not correct, I've seen strange behavior from various browsers. If changing these does not help, I would try to eliminate the ajax post, to verify that you are infact sending the correct data.

If you're using jQuery, the `$.ajax()` method has a noCache option you may wish to investiage as well.

Comment: But the data is being correctly sent... the file arrives and I can save it with no problem... the problem arises sending the json response.

Answer (score 0):

after I debuged the uploader's code, i discovered the problem, this happened to me, the problem is the response's parse, so, you must put a double quote on the hash to, like this:

```
"{\"success\": true, \"hash\": \"" + _myHash + "\"}"
```

Comment: Yes, both property names (and string values) need to be quoted.

      Response.ContentType = "text/html";
      Response.Write("{\"success\":true, \"name\":\"" + filekey + "\", \"path\":\"" + imageUrl + "\"}");